# Laravel: select students who do not have payment made in the month

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I want to make a list of students who did not make payment in the current month, or never made a payment.
it is possible to do with a single query builder, or eloquent function?
With the code below I can do exactly the opposite of what I want :/

```
$indebted = DB::table('students')->where('students.active',1)   
            ->leftJoin('payments', 'students.id', '=', 'payments.user_id')
            ->whereMonth('payments.created_at','=', $today->month)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Depending on how large your data is planned to be, using these "helper" functions are rotten for database optimisation if you don't index your data properly. Essentially they wrap the date column around a function, eg MONTH(payments.created_at) = '05' - this will force a sequential scan on that column as the function is volatile. To optimise this, you'll need to either create functional indexes "CREATE INDEX idx_blah ON payments (month(created_at))" or do a date range "->whereBetween('payments.created_at', [$today->startOfMonth, $today->endOfMonth]) (assuming $today is a Carbon date)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what value you are passing here.

```
$today->month
```

Instead of this $today->month you have to pass exact month here

Please try this

```
$indebted = DB::table('students')->where('students.active',1)   
            ->leftJoin('payments', 'students.id', '=', 'payments.user_id')
            ->whereMonth('payments.created_at','=', 06)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the students ids who made payments in Current month and year

```
$payments= DB::table('payments')
            ->whereMonth('created_at',date('m'))
            ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
            ->pluck('user_id')->all();
```

use  **whereNotIn('id',[students ids who made payments])**

```
$students = DB::table('students')
            ->whereNotIn('id',$payments)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Raw SQL in this kind of situation
I am assuming you are using mysql database

```
$sql=SELECT * from students s LEFT JOIN payments p ON s.id=p.user_id
WHERE s.active=1 AND (p.created_at is NULL or MONTH(MAX(p.created_at) < MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()))  )

$students = DB::connection('mysql')->select( DB::raw(" $sql"));
foreach($students as $aStudent){
     ...
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get student who do not have payments made in this month

```
$students = App\student::whereDoesntHave('payments', function (Builder $query) {
      $query->whereMonth('payments.created_at',$today->month);
})->where('active',1)->get();
```